# Android 13 Tiramisu deeplink not opening when typed on browser but opens when launched from messaging app

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm having a weird issue with dynamic links on Android 13. In prior Android versions, I don't have the same issue.

When I type a valid link on my browser (see notes) and then press enter, the browser tries to load that link and then shows the message `We're sorry the requested URL was not found on this server`.
If that link is shared with me, for example, in a messaging app, when I click on it, the deep link loads, and the app is launched as expected.

Here is how I'm declaring my intent filter.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="m">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="${productionHost}" android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="${developmentHost}" android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Some notes:

- The deep link that I'm trying to load is from an app that is not yet released - `android:host="${developmentHost}"`
- Tested several browsers with two specific behaviors:
  1 - Chrome and Edge show the message `We're sorry the requested URL was not found on this server`.
  2 - Opera launches the Play Store, and of course, it shows an error since my app isn't yet published.
  3 - I have no issues with the link with lower Android versions.

Any idea of what is wrong?